# Error receiving JSON (POST) via WCF

Tags: c#, json, wcf, http, visual-studio-2015

So my WCF service needs to be able to receive a JSON POST request, let's say:

```
{
    "firstname": "Billy",
    "lastname": "Jean"
}
```

With headers:

```
"Content-Type": "application/json"
```

So to do that, I've come up with the following.

My Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/PostOmnis", 
        Method = "POST", 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    System.Net.HttpStatusCode GetOmnisJson(Stream json);
}
```

My class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public class MyMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
    {
        public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Raw; // always
        }
    }
    static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        CustomBinding result = new CustomBinding(new WebHttpBinding());
        WebMessageEncodingBindingElement webMEBE = result.Elements.Find<WebMessageEncodingBindingElement>();
        webMEBE.ContentTypeMapper = new MyMapper();
        return result;
    }

    public System.Net.HttpStatusCode GetOmnisJson(Stream inputJsonStream)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputJsonStream);
        string inputJson = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // parse JSON string
        .....
        ...
        .

        // return HTTP 200
        return System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
```

However, sending some JSON via [Postman](http://getpostman.com) such as:

[image]
[image]

Gives me the following error:

> Incoming message for operation 'GetOmnisJson' (contract 'IService1'
>   with namespace 'http://tempuri.org/') contains an unrecognized http
>   body format value 'Json'. The expected body format value is 'Raw'.
>   This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on
>   the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more
>   details.

What am I missing here?

Comment: post data in header

Comment: you mean the JSON request's header? it's already there, I have a screenshot.

Comment: You operation expects a Stream, and you're posting json data, it won't work. Try to create a class the same struture of your json data (`public class Test { public string firstname { get; set; } .... }`) and change the `GetOmnisJson` operation to receive this class.

Answer (score 4):

Three options:

1. change `GetOmnisJson(Stream json)` to `GetOmnisJson(YourPeopleClass person)`
2. don't pass the `"Content-Type": "application/json"` in the header (not always an option as other people are consuming the service and you want to behave properly)
3. keep using a Stream, and create a RawContentTypeMapper that catches the content-type and still allows it to be treated as Raw. See my answer on this other question for how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54954261/631277